# Horror movie where a gang of kids plot to attack a boy

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw this live action movie on tv in the USA about 1980 to 2000, I guess.  It was made in English or else dubbed into English.

As I remember, one of the main characters was a kid about 10 to 14 I guess.  And as I remember, the kid had supernatural problems, making it a movie like Saturday the 14th (1981), Troll (1986), Troll 2 (1990). or Cameron's Closet (1988), for example.

What I specifically remember about the movie is that there was also a gang of local kids about his age who didn't like him, and plotted to attack him.  I remember the leader giving a pre battle speech to to his followers, pumping them up to attack the "wuss". And I got the impression that they intended to kill him, although they might have said something like "rid ourselves of him" instead.

And in the climax of the movie the supernatural perils struck just as the gang of kids attacked.  Some of the attackers were endangered, or harmed, or even killed by the supernatural forces and the main kid risked his life or sacrificed it to save the enemy kids.

So does anyone remember a movie like that?

Comment: Is my answer below correct?

Answer (score 10):

This might be ***[Joey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089378/)*** (1985), also known as *Making Contact*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_(1985_film)):

> The plot concerns a 9-year-old boy named Joey (Joshua Morell) who loses his father, but makes contact with what he believes is his deceased parent via a small phone and is terrorized by a ventriloquist dummy named Fletcher who is possessed by a demon. The doll summons other demons and evil forces to threaten his friends, mother, enemies, city as only Joey must go into the spirit world to destroy this evil in a battle of good vs. evil. The boy develops the power of telekinesis, which soon gets out of hand.

There's a scene around the 36:17 mark where a group of kids discuss kidnapping the main character, Joey, and torturing him. They specifically refer to him as a "wuss" in this scene.

There's also a scene around the 1:02:22 mark where Joey has to save the bullies from being trapped in a maze.